# iOS 5 - buttons stop working

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, modalviewcontroller

I am developing an app and have accidentally been running it on iOS Simulator 4.3; the app works fine.

Upon changing to iOS5 simulator, a button which is supposed to dismiss a modal view controller, no longer works? Any ideas why?

Below is my code:

(Method to call controller):

```
if (self.infoModalController == nil)
    self.infoModalController = [[[InformationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                                   NSStringFromClass([InformationViewController class]) bundle:nil] autorelease];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.infoModalController animated:YES];
```

(Method to dismiss):

```
- (void)dismissButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The view loads fine but it won't dismiss?

Cheers in advance!

Lawrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 5 you want to use presentingViewController in place of parentViewController.

Here are the relevant docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController

Update: I should mention that calling [self dismissModalViewController] from the modal will have the same result, the dismiss selector is just passed up the responder chain to the presenter.

Answer (score 0):

When dismissing a modal view controller, it's safer to just do `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`. This message can be sent to both **the parent view or the modal view**.
The solution would be to this:

```
- (void)dismissButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```